# Determine who has created a file in Win XP (NTFS)

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs

Is there a way to determine which user created a file on Win XP with NTFS?

Comment: Not natively, there may be 3rd party software that can be installed that will log this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All files on NTFS have an "**owner**" which is displayed in

- the *Owner* column in Explorer's "Detailed" view (must be added manually; right-click the header)
- *Properties - Security - Advanced - Ownership* (in XP Professional)
- `dir/q` on Command Prompt

---

On Windows NT (starting with NT 3.1, including XP, 2003, Vista, 7, and future versions), all newly created objects are owned by their creator.

This is **not limited to files**: almost everything can have an ACL attached. Examples: named pipes, Registry keys, processes, services, desktops, devices, mutexes...

- Unless someone else **takes ownership**. (Administrators can do this by using `SeTakeOwnership` privilege; non-Administrators can take ownership if the object's ACL allows it.)
- On **server editions** of Windows NT, Administrators can **assign object ownership** to another user. Consumer editions (such as Windows XP or 7) only allow taking ownership to yourself.
- In **Windows 2000 and earlier** versions, if the creator is member of the Administrators group, the objects he creates **will be owned by Administrators, not the user**. [This changed in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318825), where the user will always own objects he creates.

---

For most object types, you can even enable *auditing*, which causes all operations on the object to be logged to Security log. (You can choose which operations to log.)

For files, this can be done in *Properties - Security - Advanced - Auditing*. Use Event Viewer (`eventvwr.exe`) to see the log entries.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Now I've found out who is locking an Excel file on the network drive.

Comment: @James: Regarding network drives: next time, `fsmgmt.msc` or `net file` could be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to get these commands to work without admin rights though. It seems we will have to get the IT dept to sort it out.